# Is this really Uncle Bob??

Tags: discussion, new-users

Answer to [Can a function be too short?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64449/can-a-function-be-too-short/64514#64514) by user "Uncle Bob".

If so, welcome Uncle Bob! I'm thrilled to see you answering questions on Programmers!

Comment: Fine, but is this really a valid question for this forum? A comment in the question would have been more appropriate.

Comment: Nah. I say this is very valid for meta. Also, it is a question, in that it has a single answer. And it is easier to link than a comment. If anything, create a comment there with a link to here.

Comment: Who is Uncle Bob?

Answer (score 8):

Indeed it is! Welcome Uncle Bob.

http://twitter.com/#!/unclebobmartin/status/54097164942573568

Comment: Holy crap. This is awesum